# do something every (n) seconds in loop

Tags: php, loops, timer

I have CLI application in PHP (windows)

I have loop and i want in that loop run something every (n) seconds but not using 
sleep (i cannot stop script because its socket loop) for checking something.

how?

Comment: Why do you not want to use `sleep()`?

Comment: You can check a timedifference. `if ($last_time-time() > $n) {...}`, and update `$last_time` when that condition is true.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i cannot sleep because it's socket loop

Comment: Can't you just run a separate script concurrently which does something every X seconds with a sleep and have that independent of the current script? I doubt there's a way to "interrupt" a running PHP script every X seconds from within the same script.

Comment: do i need to compare time? There is nothing simple like timer->Start in php?

Answer (score 0):

ok got it :)

```php
$last_time = time();

while (true) {

    if (time() - $last_time > 10) {
        echo 'ok!';
        $last_time = time();
    }
}
```